# Cannot check if user has permissions

Tags: laravel, permissions, laravel-permission

Im using the laravel spatie/permissions bundle. 
Working with that bundle i ran in to a problem. I have made multiple roles and have used the `$role->givePermissionTo('view users')` method to give my role the permission to see my users.

Now when i use `@can('view users')` i cannot see the link.

i made it like this:

```
 @can('view users')
     <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="{{ route('user.index') }}">
             {{ __('User Management') }}
         </a>
     </li>
 @endcan
```

When i check if the user has the permission it says it does. How come it doesnt show the link?

Comment: Your backend code would be nice

Comment: Not much backend code to be submitted., just using the $role->givePermissionTo method to assign the permission to the role. After that i started checking. In the database i see that the Role is assigned to the model and the permission is assigned to the role. So it seems like everything is fine on that end.